# Issue passing tfvars to tf files

Tags: terraform

Another terraform question...

I have a tfvar variable called "IsMultiAz", its value is set to "true" (boolean, but in string as recommended).

When I use this in RDS to control the multi-az variable, I get this error:

```
aws_db_instance.kong_private_rds: Error modifying DB Instance kongprivateinstance: InvalidParameterCombination: No modifications were requested
```

What is the way to pass bool variables from tfvars to my tf files?

Comment: What does the plan show? Can you recreate this issue with a [mcve] so we can reproduce this please?

Answer (score 0):

Terraform 0.12 adds rich support for data types. Give it try by upgrading your terraform to 0.12+ and use boolean without string quotes.